# What good email service alternatives are available for academics in China?

Tags: email, software, tools, china

I am based in China and am desperate to find a good email service as a researcher. The university email has suspicious delays and is probably censored. I used to rely on Gmail, but Google is blocked in China, and my emails from my Gmail are often blocked by our university. Are there good email alternatives for academics?

Comment: Many of my students use Microsoft Outlook

Comment: Is it not possible to use a VPN to access Google and its services?

Comment: Is it possible in China to get your own domain with hosted email?

Comment: @justauser China has been cracking down on VPNs too https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/jan/23/china-vpn-cleanup-great-firewall-censorship . From what I understand, they use traffic analysis and deep packet inspection, so even rolling out one on your own cloud server won't help.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Thanks. Moved away from Microsoft 10 years ago after tried linux. Guess it's time to move back.

Comment: @justauser If I send emails to my university address through Gmail, it will be blocked. Since many of my collaborators are Chinese, Gmail becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Louic Thanks, getting a domain is beyond my skill, but I will look through it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni VPN still works to some degree. Would be a nightmare if they ban it completely (Baidu Scholar Search is a joke).

Comment: I don't know if there's anything specifically for academics w.r.t. e-mail services but for privacy-conscious folks, protonmail and tutanota are quite popular. Neither is obviously free though but probably CCP won't come banging at your door for paying for those services... Hopefully...

Comment: What about ProtonMail? They claim, their setup worked for Snowden, Assange, and Co. Might also work in China.

Comment: Is there any reason you expect a different answer "for academics" than in general? To me, this looks like what they call a [boat programming question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/164803) on StackOverflow, i.e. this is not really related to academia.

Comment: @Lodinn I mean emails that don't look too unprofessional and won't be blocked by most systems. In our university, all Gmail messages are blocked, and I wonder whether Gmails are discriminated as such. Proton seems to be good (A student just recommended).

Comment: @Szabolcs it is related to academic culture, and practice.

Comment: @gastro This is the first time I hear of Gmail being blocked by "most systems". Usually, the issue is [another](https://www.technology.pitt.edu/security/best-practices-blacklisting-prevention) [way around](https://uit.stanford.edu/emailcalendar/spam/blocklist). I've had some issues with a "self-hosted" mail server on a VM of a big cloud provider but that's about it, really.

Comment: AFAIK Outlook is not blocked. So that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is still working, and you can use Outlook Mail to connect to your university mail address through POP, etc. It might be a good idea to automatically reroute your Gmail emails to your outlook address as well.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that Yahoo must work in China, but some people note about the possible lags. I advise you to register on QQ Mail — it's allowed in China. Well, if you're not afraid to use VPN, you can access all Western email providers using VPN.